# How to apply regex sub to a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file I wish to apply a regex replacement to with python.

So far I have the following

```
reader = csv.reader(open('ffrk_inventory_relics.csv', 'r'))
writer = csv.writer(open('outfile.csv','w'))
for row in reader:
    reader = re.sub(r'\+','z',reader)
```

Which is giving me the following error:

```
Script error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ffrk_inventory_tracker_v1.6.py", line 22, in response
    getRelics(data['equipments'], 'ffrk_inventory_relics')
  File "ffrk_inventory_tracker_v1.6.py", line 72, in getRelics
    reader = re.sub(r'\+','z',reader)
  File "c:\users\baconcatbug\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\re.py",
line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

After googling to not much luck, I would like to ask the community here how to open the csv file correctly so I can use re.sub on it and then write out the altered csv file back to the same filename.

Comment: Why are you passing `reader` to `re.sub`? Pass `row` instead.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye `row` is a `list` and not a proper arg for `re.sub` either.

Comment: @schwobaseggl You're right. Brainfart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need `csv` you can use `replace` with regular `open`:

```
with open('ffrk_inventory_relics.csv', 'r') as reader, open('outfile.csv','w') as writer:
    for row in reader:
        writer.write(row.replace('+','z'))
```

Comment: The + and z were just test strings to replace, the final replacement is a big regex argument

Comment: Sure you can change that row into desired regex in sense `row = re.sub('\+', 'z', row)`

Comment: The following code is working, but how do I make outfile.csv replace ffrk_inventory_relics.csv? (No idea why the formatting is mangled I don't know how to express the below in a code block)


 `with open('ffrk_inventory_relics.csv', 'r') as reader, open('outfile.csv','w') as writer:`
 
  `for row in reader:`
  
   `row = re.sub('(\+*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,\ 0)', ' (Core)\\g<1>', row)`
   
   `writer.write(row)`

Comment: Have you considered using `pandas`? I think it would solve your problem.#

Comment: I have no idea what pandas is or how it would help.

Answer (score 1):

`csv.reader(open('ffrk_inventory_relics.csv', 'r'))` is creating a list of lists, and when you iterate over it and pass each value to `re.sub`, you are passing a list, not a string. Try this:

```
import re
import csv
final_data = [[re.sub('\+', 'z', b) for b in i] for i in csv.reader(open('ffrk_inventory_relics.csv', 'r'))]
write = csv.writer(open('ffrk_inventory_relics.csv'))
write.writerows(final_data)
```

Comment: And how do I write final_data to the csv file?